# Error analysing memory dump in bluescreenview

Tags: bsod, bluescreenview

I'm getting an error when trying to analyse a memory dump in nirsoft's bluescreenview

The system that the dump is from is Windows 10

The system I am running bluescreenview from is Windows 7

I placed the dump file here

```
C:\Users\User\Downloads\ff>dir
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is 4645-5DCE

 Directory of C:\Users\User\Downloads\ff

13/09/2020  19:05    <DIR>          .
13/09/2020  19:05    <DIR>          ..
14/08/2020  16:05       649,811,537 MEMORY.DMP
               1 File(s)    649,811,537 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  140,474,257,408 bytes free

C:\Users\User\Downloads\ff>
```

I pointed Nirsoft's BlueScreenView to the file

[image]

I click OK, and then it says

```
Exception C0000005 at address 00000001400062B1 in module BlueScreenView.exe
Registers: 
EAX=0000000000000000 EBX=4547415045474130 ECX=0000000000000000 EDX=0000000051C75FF2
ESI=0000000026BB5651 EDI=000000000012D070 EBP=000000002B0C0000 ESP=000000000012A858
EIP=00000001400062B1
Stack Data:   0F 67 00 40 01 00 00 00   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   DA 0C 06 00 00 00 00 00   69 8B A8 77 00 00 00 00   A4 D0 12 00 00 00 00 00   7F 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   38 01 00 00 00 00 00 00   E0 03 00 00 00 00 00 00   00 00 0C 2B 00 00 00 00   51 56 BB 26 00 00 00 00   C8 DC 12 00 00 00 00 00   F0 76 A8 77 00 00 00 00   82 02 00 00 00 00 00 00   0C 14 00 40 01 00 00 00   40 27 89 00 00 00 00 00
Code Data: 8B 42 0C 48 03 02 48 3B D8 72 2B 41 83 C3 01 48 83 C2 10 45 3B 59 7C 72 E2 49 3B 59 48 72 33 41 8B 41 2C 49 03 41 48 48 3B D8 73 26 41 8B 41 28 41 2B 41 48 EB 05 8B 42 08 2B 02 03 C3 4C 3B D1 74 0B 41 3B 40 18 73 05 8B C8 49 03 CA 48 8B C1 EB 02 33 C0 48 8B 5C 24 08 C3 CC 48 89 5C 24 08 48 89 7C 24 10 4D 8B 48 10 33 C9 4C 8B DA 4C 3B C9 74 11 41 81 78 18 00 10 00 00 4D 8D 91 00 10
```

[image]

And if I click "continue" it stays in BlueScreenView.  If I click "Terminate application" then it closes BlueScreenView.

So it looks like opening the dump file, crashes bluescreenview and causes bluescreenview to give a memory dump from itself crashing!

I wonder if maybe bluescreenview is not compatible with a memory dump file from windows 10?

Comment: (1) Can you try Blue Screen View on the Windows 10 system to answer your last question.   (2) Try entering the file (including the path to the file directly under "Load a Single Mini Dump File and enable (radio button) "Load a Single Mini Dump File.  I use this method and the Nirsoft BSV opens any valid mini dump file. I have not tried viewing a Windows 10 file on Windows 7. I have the Nirsoft utility on both systems and use it where the BSOD occurs. Try this

Comment: I just took a dump file from my Windows 10 machine (created in Windows 10, copied it to my Windows 7 machine and opened it with Nirsoft Blue Screen View on Windows 7 so the files are definitely compatible.